# 2D threads in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu

I'm trying to use 2D threads in CUDA. `threadIDx.x` and `blockIdx.x` work fine, but `threadIdx.y` and `blockIdx.y` don't work. The .y ones are always 0.

Here is my code:

```
#define N 16
__global__ void add(int* a) {
    int i=threadIdx.x;
    int j=threadIdx.y;
    a[i] = j;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a[N];
    const int size = N*sizeof(int);
    int *da;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&da, size);
    add<<<1, N>>>(da);
    cudaMemcpy(a, da, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("Thread indices:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    cudaFree(da);
    return 0;
}
```

The result for `a[i] = j;` or `a[j] = j;`

Thread indices:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

and for `a[i] = i;`

Thread indices:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
I tried using

```
#define M 4
#define N 4
...
int i = (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x) + threadIdx.x; 
int j = (blockDim.y * blockIdx.y) + threadIdx.y;
...
add<<<M, N>>>(da);
...
```

and result is same: .x ones are fine but .y ones are all 0. Can anyone help me fixing this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing blocks and threads with dimensions.

`add <<<M,N>>>` is interpreted as `add<<<dim3(M,1,1),dim3(N,1,1)>>>` where `M` is the number of blocks and `N` is the number of threads per kernel.

If you want to have `MxN` blocks with `MxN` threads call `add<<<dim3(M,N),dim3(M,N)>>>`

I would recommend [Udacity CUDA course](https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-parallel-programming--cs344) for beginners, it is very beginner friendly.

> I want M blocks with N threads per block.

Well then `add<<<M,N>>>` is correct but it is 1 dimensional, there is no `y` to it. If you want to locate the thread use this code.

```
int index = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x
```

There is no `y` in it. The entire thing is 1D. Each block can only have a limited number of threads (64 or 128 usually) that is why threads and blocks are separated. There are a lot of nuances to it. I would recommend the Udacity course it helped me a lot.

Comment: Thank you I will take that udacity course. But I don't want `MxN` blocks with `MxN` threads. I want M blocks with N threads per block. And what about the first type `add <<<1,N>>>`? I just couldn't understand why `threadIdx.y` is always 0

Comment: because when the first number is a scalar, you will be launching a 1D **grid**.  A 1D grid always has `blockIdx.y` == 0 for every block.  When the second number is a scalar, you will be launching a 1D **threadblock**.  A 1D threadblock always has `threadIdx.y` == 0 for every thread in the block.  It is 1-dimensional, so the second thread dimension is zero, always.

Comment: Thank you @RobertCrovella your comment helped me a lot